Entity Framework Core one-to-zero-or-one not binding included relations when querying
I have an Entity Framework Core code-first database with a one-to-one-or-zero relationship set up like this:
public class PrimaryRow 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public OptionalRow { get; set; }
}

public class OptionalRow 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OptionalValue { get; set; }

    public int PrimaryRowId { get; set; }
    public PrimaryRow PrimaryRow { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<PrimaryRow> PrimaryRows { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OptionalRow> OptionalRows { get; set; }
}

This creates the following tables:
CREATE TABLE "PrimaryRows" 
(
    "Id" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_PrimaryRows" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "Value" TEXT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE "OptionalRows" 
(
    "Id" INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_OptionalRows" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "OptionalValue" TEXT NULL,
    "PrimaryRowId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_OptionalRows_PrimaryRows_PrimaryRowId" FOREIGN KEY ("PrimaryRowId") REFERENCES "PrimaryRows" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
)

I query the data using this code:
var rows = await MyContext.PrimaryRows
                          .Include(p => p.OptionalRow)
                          .ToListAsync();

I can see that this generates the following SQL:
SELECT "p"."Id", "p"."Value", "p0"."Id", "p0"."OptionalValue", "p0"."PrimaryRowId"
FROM "PrimaryRows" AS "p"
LEFT JOIN "OptionalRows" AS "p0" ON "p"."Id" = "p0"."PrimaryRowId"

Which does indeed include the optional relational data.
However, when I look at the contents of rows the OptionalRow property is NULL! So the querying works, but the data binding doesn't.
What am I missing here?

Does OptionalRows contain record with match by PrimaryRowId?

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes. The generated SQL query contains data in the LEFT JOIN part.

What data does that query return when you execute it? Also, can you include the actual entities and their configuration? Often attempts to simplify an example result in changes that actually hide the real cause for the problem.

A couple of things to check and eliminate.
First would be to eliminate the obvious: Is it using the same database you expect at runtime? Often a different database connection string is preserved in a config file that at runtime it ends up executing on a database you don't expect. You are capturing the SQL
Second, A typical cause for data in one-to-one relationships not coming back as expected has to do with the default way EF expects to associate one-to-one relationships, by PK to PK. Identifying this issue can be obfuscated in attempts to provide a simpler example in a question.
So for instance with:
public class PrimaryRow 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public OptionalRow? OptionalRow { get; set; }
}

public class OptionalRow 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OptionalValue { get; set; }

    public int PrimaryRowId { get; set; }
    public PrimaryRow PrimaryRow { get; set; }
}

By default EF when set up with a:
modelBuilder.Entity<PrimaryRow>()
    .HasOne(x => x.OptionalRow)
    .WithOne(x => x.PrimaryRow);

... it is going to try and join these rows on the Id PK in both tables. This can result in the wrong OptionalRow coming back, or no OptionalRow. When configuring with a dedicated FK column you need to tell EF which property on what entity to use:
modelBuilder.Entity<PrimaryRow>()
    .HasOne(x => x.OptionalRow)
    .WithOne(x => x.PrimaryRow)
    .HasForeignKey<OptionalRow>(x => x.PrimaryRowId);

This would show up in the real captured SQL which would have:
LEFT JOIN "OptionalRows" AS "p0" ON "p"."Id" = "p0"."Id" // PK to PK

.. rather than
LEFT JOIN "OptionalRows" AS "p0" ON "p"."Id" = "p0"."PrimaryRowId" // PK to FK

... in the case that you might have inadvertently substituted the SQL from the real tables in your project for your example naming without noticing it was joining on the PK.

"Is it using the same database you expect at runtime" It was, then it wasn't! I didn't specifically start looking for this until I removed all migration, deleted the database, and it started complaining about creating a table that already existed. It turns out the application had stopped reading the correct appsettings, though I've no idea why. After saving and re-saving the appsettings, and restarting both the application and Visual Studio a few times it suddenly started reading the correct appsettings again and things are working as expected with the relation :D
